# Netsuite - SuiteCloud Development Framework - GitHub Integration - CI/CD

Tags: node.js, netsuite, cicd, suitecloud

We are improving our CI/CD process and we understand that we need to use GitHub (or similar) for a better version control..

We would like to integrate SuiteCloud with Github to upload ALL our objects in order to track an monitor any changes. Also, we are planning to use branches to deploy code in our instances. Ex: Master = Production. Dev Branch = Sandbox1, Homologation = Sandbox2.

So... is possible to do it? And how? Any experiences to be shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SDF manipulates text (xml) files their management is no different than for any other git based CI/CD process.

Netsuite has java and node based CLI tools that can be incorporated in Git Actions for automated deployments.

You'll have some fun if you want to automate testing as that can be problematic with any live database.